# Using variable inside PHP function (Laravel 5)

Tags: php, variables, laravel-5

I have problems using data inside a laravel function, here is a example:

```
    public function csvUnique($id){ 

          $date1= ''.$id.' 00:00:00';
          $date2= ''.$id.' 23:59:59';       

        \Excel::create('Customer list', function ($excel) {

         $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function ($sheet) {

             echo  $date1; 
             echo  $date1; 

             });

            })->export('csv');

} //end csv
```

`$id` is passed value,and I can see value if use `dd($id)`. The problem is: How to pass values `date1` and `date2` inside functions?

I tried with global, same error:

```
**Undefined variable: date1**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to inject the variables into the scope of the closure. This is done with `use`:

```
\Excel::create('Customer list', function ($excel) use ($date1, $date2) {

     $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function ($sheet) use ($date1, $date2) {
         echo  $date1; 
         echo  $date1; 
     });

})->export('csv');
```

In your case you have to do it twice. First pass it inside the first anonymous function and from there to the second one.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16959577/1903366) for a very detailed explanation of the whole topic. The section *Crossing scope boundaries* is especially relevant for your question.

Comment: That solve problem! Tnx